# Is there a formula for electric serial connection with different voltage/current?

Tags: voltage, current-measurement

I installed a Solar pad(24V/9A/220W) and connected to my grid-tie inverter. and I'm planning to install another, but due to space problem, I may not be able to add another panel the same size...

[image]

so I drew a diagram(sorry for the sloppy drawing - dont know electric circuit symbols) on how I'm planning to connect the new one. If I get to install 24-volt solar panel then I'll just connect it parallel, but dont know...

So anyway, this is the question: 
If I connect the lines like that, how does the electric output comes out? 36volts? and the current?
Is there something like a formula I could use to calculate?

I think the inverter itself could handle extra volts, since it said it could take up to 60 volts....

Comment: What Asmydof said about series and parallel connection is essentially correct. As shown you can have ~~~=: 36V at 6A or (probably) 12V at 15A approx - with e the 36V arrangement being both the safer and most powerful. The best solution if you can manage it is to add an additional 12V 3A panel in parallel with the 12V 6A - giving 6+3 = 12V 9a and oberall total of 36V 9A. If that is not possible and you have not bought the 6V panel yet then the test solution is either a 9A panel at as much V as will fit in space available (perhaps 8V 9A which is non standard) OR a 24V panel at as much I as ....

Comment: ... will fit eg 24V 3A. | You can then have either 24V 9A + 8V 9A = 32V 9A OR 24V 9A + 24V 3A = 24V 12A. | The latter is perhaps the least certain but either will be OKish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For traditional power sources with a limited current and a limited voltage (99.9% of all electric power sources?!) the rule is simple:

If you put two in series the peak output voltage will be the peak voltages added together, at normal operation the maximum current will be the current of the lowest unit.

Putting in parallel with different voltages will be a bit different, let's keep it at: better not. Too many options depending on source types.

For solar panels the current thing *MIGHT* be a bit different. It is possible that at higher load currents the upper panel will drop to very low voltages, but be capable of conducting the higher 9A.

However, the total power output will most likely be horrible, compared to exactly matched cells with the same total surface. Especially if your inverter starts to attempt MPPT with mismatched cells in series. Always best to either cascade/join panels of the exact same type, or use an inverter system with multiple inputs if that's not an option and let the electronics handle it all in a smart way. There's too many variables and risks in serialising different panel types.

If both panels are the exact same voltage and are mounted on the same surface and in the same direction, you can put them in parallel, and their current outputs will be added together at that voltage at the moment of peak illumination to a good/predictable degree.

Comment: Ok.. think I got it. so... 

Serial: only adds up voltage and current goes with lowest current

/ Parallel: lowest voltage, adding up current. 

Aaaaaand.... worst efficiency  if I decide to connect them in any way.

Thank you for the answer. Decided going parallel, using dc-inverter.

Comment: @Mr.Solid Generally speaking, yes. Solar cells are a bit annoying to fully predict, since a lot depends on the material/crystal composition and purity in regards of how it acts as a conductor when it cannot generate power itself, or not enough of it.